# How to remove whitespaces from string literals in Rust during compile time?

Tags: rust

Assuming I have multiline string nicely formatted in my source code:

```
let style_text = ".styled {
border: 0;
line-height: 3.5;
padding: 0 20px;"
```

I don't want to transmit unnecessary whitespace to the browser, but I also don't want to remove it for every request.

How can I remove all whitespace at compile time?

Comment: You can do it with a procedural macro. But that's going to be a difficult route, which may not be worth the effort.

Comment: If you go down that road, make sure to use a proper minfier (e.g. https://crates.io/crates/css-minifier) rather than just stripping spaces, or you'll end up doing bad things, like turning `margin: 0 0 10px 10px` into `margin:0010px10px`.

Comment: Perhaps a build script is a happy medium: have it process some input CSS files, emitting the minified output which the crate src then pulls in as a constant str with the `include_str!` macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are likely overkill for something like this, which would be the compile-time option.

Next best to compile-time is to just do it once.

```
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref STYLES: String = minify_styles(
        ".styled {
            border: 0;
            line-height: 3.5;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }"
    );
}
```

Now use `STYLES` instead of the literal string.

When implementing `minify_styles`, make sure to use a proper [CSS minifier](https://crates.io/crates/css-minifier), rather than just stripping whitespace. Whitespace can be contextually significant in CSS, e.g. you don't want to turn `padding: 0 20px` into `padding:020px`.